# JS: Find object by field in a complex Parent-Child Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I use **Javascript ES6** and have an issue.

I have an Array:

```
var commentList = [
   {'id': 1, text: 'A', children: [{'id': 2, text: 'B' }] },
   {'id': 4, text: 'asd', children: [] },
   {'id': 5, text: 'vx', children: [{'id': 7, text: 'xxss' }] },
   {'id': 8, text: 'ghfdh', children: [{'id': 15, text: 'I want to take this' }] },
   {'id': 10, text: 'A', children: [{'id': 18, text: 'Bsda' }] },
]
```

This is an Array with Parent - Child Structure. How can I get Exactly object `{'id': 15, text: 'I want to take this' }` if I just have **ID only**

I tried but not work

`var object = commentList.find(o => o.id === 15)` => `undefined`

Comment: Can those children arrays be nested arbitrarily or is there only a single level?

Comment: Look up recursion

Comment: `commentList.concat(...commentList.map(o => o.children)).find(o => o.id == 15)` should do it

Answer (score 7):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by checking the `id` or taking the children.

```js
const find = (array, id) => {
    var result;
    array.some(o => result = o.id === id ? o : find(o.children || [], id));
    return result;
};

var commentList = [{ id: 1, text: 'A', children: [{ id: 2, text: 'B' }] }, { id: 4, text: 'asd', children: [] }, { id: 5, text: 'vx', children: [{ id: 7, text: 'xxss' }] }, { id: 8, text: 'ghfdh', children: [{ id: 15, text: 'I want to take this' }] }, { id: 10, text: 'A', children: [{ id: 18, text: 'Bsda' }] }];

console.log(find(commentList, 15));
```

Comment: Tiny code, But Ninja, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to find the item recursively. If there's no item, the function will return undefined:

```js
const find = (array = [], id) => {
  for (const item of array) {
    const result = item.id === id ? item : find(item.children, id);
    if(result) return result;
  }
};

const commentList = [{ id: 1, text: 'A', children: [{ id: 2, text: 'B' }] }, { id: 4, text: 'asd', children: [] }, { id: 5, text: 'vx', children: [{ id: 7, text: 'xxss' }] }, { id: 8, text: 'ghfdh', children: [{ id: 15, text: 'I want to take this' }] }, { id: 10, text: 'A', children: [{ id: 18, text: 'Bsda' }] }];

const result = find(commentList, 15);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Man , you are awesome. I have been looking for this for long time. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the logic into a function and then iterate over the children array and return the one you requested (The first match).

```js
var commentList = [
   {'id': 1, text: 'A', children: [{'id': 2, text: 'B' }] },
   {'id': 4, text: 'asd', children: [] },
   {'id': 5, text: 'vx', children: [{'id': 7, text: 'xxss' }] },
   {'id': 8, text: 'ghfdh', children: [{'id': 15, text: 'I want to take this' }] },
   {'id': 10, text: 'A', children: [{'id': 18, text: 'Bsda' }] },
]

const findChildById = (id, arr) => {
  const result = arr.find(o => o.id === id)
  if (result) return result
  for (const cm of arr) {
    const result = cm.children.find(o => o.id === id)
    if (result) return result
  }
}
console.log(findChildById(10, commentList))
```

Comment: …assuming that you already know that the id you have belongs to a child object

Comment: @Bergi, what do you mean? The OP said he wants to search the children array. If the id does not exist than a custom string is returned

Comment: The OP never said that he wants to search only the children arrays or that he wants to find a child.

Comment: @Bergi, I see, Thanks for noticing. I've updated the code for finding in parent and only than finding in children.

Answer (score 1):

Following very simple and basic code should work for you. I assume that all id-s of all children elements in all arrays are unique. This code will find the first element that matches the id we are looking for;

```
var result = null;
var idToSearch = 15;
var i=0;
var j=0;

for(i=0; i<commentList.length; i++){
    var currentChildren = commentList[i].children;
    if(currentChildren && currentChildren.length > 0){
        for(j=0; j<currentChildren.length; j++){
            if(currentChildren[j].id === idToSearch){
                result=currentChildren[j];
                j=currentChildren.length;
                i=commentList.length;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```